# How to limit Flask-SQLAlchemy float to 2 decimals?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this model

```
class AccountsModel(db.Model):
    accountId = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    total = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
```

I want my database to have "total" numbers with 2 decimals like 0.00

Numbers like 1.23 work, but  1.2 stays 1.2 and 1 becomes 1.0

I've tried:

```
total = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2), nullable=False)
total = db.Column(db.Float(2), nullable=False)
total = db.Column(db.Float(5,2), nullable=False)
```

I also tried Numeric instead of Float, but it breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed precision / scale, you're probably looking for the [sqlalchemy `Numeric` type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric) instead of `Float`. Floats don't carry precision or scale information.

This [Microsoft-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) document defines precision and scale as:

> Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

So, the `total` column definition could be defined in sqlalchemy as

```
      total = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=2), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Actually I already tried that. If I do something like
account = AccountsModel(accountId=id, name=args["name"], surname=args["surname"], total=0)
I still get 0.0 . I don't know if it's because I'm using flask-sqlalchemy instead of sqlalchemy

Comment: hmm, maybe its a display formatting issue then. How are you _printing_ your total? Do you have a format specifier for the number of decimal places you want to show?

Comment: I am printing them in an HTML page using Jinja2 and it works fine, but I was looking for a way to have them directly like that in the db.
 `{{ "€{:,.2f}".format(total) }}` prints them correctly.

Comment: If you use numeric, then the value will be stored exactly and you won't encounter floating point math issues. However, for printing you should use the format specifier